# Python dataclass, one attribute referencing other

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-class

```py
@dataclass
class Stock:
    symbol: str
    price: float = get_price(symbol)
```

Can a `dataclass` attribute access to the other one? In the above example, one can create a `Stock` by providing a symbol and the price. If price is not provided, it **defaults** to a price which we get from some function `get_price`. Is there a way to reference symbol?

This example generates error `NameError: name 'symbol' is not defined`.

Comment: Complicated initialization behaviour like that belongs in a proper class instead of a dataclass.

Comment: I agree, but we may differ if this case should be considered complex. There is no business logic except getting a price if not provided. Function as default value works fine in `dataclasses` except the problem I discussed (not able to refer to another parameter). I think the answer from @S.B. below can help use `dataclass` in such simple cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`__post_init__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#post-init-processing) here. Because it's going to be called after `__init__`, you have your attributes already populated so do whatever you want to do there:

```py
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass


def get_price(name):
    # logic to get price by looking at `name`.
    return 1000.0


@dataclass
class Stock:
    symbol: str
    price: Optional[float] = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.price is None:
            self.price = get_price(self.symbol)


obj1 = Stock("boo", 2000.0)
obj2 = Stock("boo")
print(obj1.price)  # 2000.0
print(obj2.price)  # 1000.0
```

So if user didn't pass `price` while instantiating, `price` is None. So you can check it in `__post_init__` and ask it from `get_price`.

---

There is also another shape of the above answer which basically adds nothing more to the existing one. I just added for the records since someone might attempt to do this as well and wonder how is it different with the previous one:

```py
@dataclass
class Stock:
    symbol: str
    price: InitVar[Optional[float]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, price):
        self.price = get_price(self.symbol) if price is None else price
```

You mark the `price` as `InitVar` and you can get it with a parameter named `price` in the `__post_init__` method.

Comment: This is brilliant - the cleanest solution.

Comment: Based on the post-init docs referenced, better yet (if you explicitly don't want price to be part of the constructor), then `price: float = dataclasses.field(init=False)`

Answer (score 4):

If the price is always derivable from the symbol, I would go with a `@property`. Keeps the code lean and it looks like an attribute from the outside:

```py
def get_price(symbol):
    return 123

@dataclass
class Stock:
    symbol: str

    @property
    def price(self):
        return get_price(symbol)

stock = Stock("NVDA")
print(stock.price) # 123
```

If you want to have a settable attribute that also has a default value that is derived from the other fields, you may just want to implement your own `__init__` or `__post_init__` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599883/837451).

If this is something you encounter a lot and need more sophisticated ways to handle it, I would recommend looking into [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) and `validator`s.

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import validator
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

def get_price(symbol):
    return 123.0

@dataclass
class Stock:
    symbol: str
    price: Optional[float] = None

    @validator('price')
    def validate_price(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return v or get_price(values["symbol"])


print(Stock("NVDA"))
#> Stock(symbol='NVDA', price=123.0)
print(Stock("NVDA", 456))
#> Stock(symbol='NVDA', price=456.0)
```

Comment: I thought of property before asking, but that changes the workflow if someone really has a value to provide (default only in case no value provided). `pydantic` looks nice but looks more involved in this use case. I'll go through the docs to understand the use cases.